# rails 5 - scope with #or and #joins: how to work around limitations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.1

`User` has many `Posts`

`Post` has many `Comments`

`User` has many `Comments`

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  ..stuff...

  scope :created_by, ->(user) { where(creator: user) }
  scope :with_comments_by, ->(user) { joins(:comments).where('comments.creator_id = ?'. user.id) }
  ##########========= this is my failure:
  scope :related_to, ->(user) { created_by(user).or(with_comments_by(user) }
```

(not my real models, just sticking with SO basic app structure)

This last scope doesn't work, as is [clearly noted](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/05/30/rails-5-adds-or-support-in-active-record.html):

> The two relations must be structurally compatible, they must be scoping the same model, and they must differ only by WHERE or HAVING.

So, how do I get around this? (*please* don't say a messy, long SQL sentence)

I want to be able to call `Posts.related_to(user)` and get one ActiveRecord collection of all posts the user *created* or *commented on*.

---

I was headed down this path, but I know this is perverse:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  ..stuff...

  scope :created_by, ->(user) { where(creator: user) }
  scope :with_comments_by, ->(user) { joins(:comments).where('comments.creator_id = ?'. user.id) }
  ##########========= this is my failure:
  # scope :related_to, ->(user) { created_by(user).or(with_comments_by(user) }

  def self.related_to(user)
    ary = []
    ary << Post.created_by(user).map(&:id)
    ary << Post.with_comments_by(user).map(&:id)
    Post.find(ary.uniq)
    # so...bad...so yucky
  end
```

Help me, SO community. I'm trapped in my own mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `with_comments_by` scope isn't quite what you want. That scope should be finding posts whose comments have a comment from `user` so you should be saying exactly that:

```
scope :with_comments_by, ->(user) { where(id: Comment.select(:post_id).where(creator_id: user.id)) }
```

You should be able to use that scope with your `or` in `related_to` without any complaints.

This version of `with_comments_by` will also neatly take care of the duplicate posts that your JOIN could produce if someone has commented multiple times on one post.